# Python pip install (using proxy) cannot resolve server in a VM behind a VPN

Tags: python, ubuntu, proxy, pip, vpn

My setup:

- Windows 7 64-bit host on Corporate network
- Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit VirtualBox guest

  - Ubuntu guest configured with VirtualBox Bridged adapter
  - Proxy settings confirmed working: Firefox can access Corporate intranet sites as well as internet, `apt-get install` works as well

Here's what I've done to configure the proxy up to this point:

/etc/profile.d/proxy.sh:

```
export http_proxy="http://<my_proxy>:<my_port>"
export https_proxy="http://<my_proxy>:<my_port>"
export ftp_proxy="http://<my_proxy>:<my_port>"
```

To get aptitude to work, modified /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy “http://<my_proxy>:<my_port>"
```

To keep the env vars around when using sudo, modified /etc/sudoers.d/proxy:

```
Defaults env_keep += "http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy"
```

I've also set the HTTP/HTTPS/FTP Proxy settings in Settings->Network->NetWork Proxy, and clicked "Apply system wide".

The problem is that when I try `pip install` (with or without `sudo`), it fails with the error:

```
$ pip -vv install git-review
Downloading/unpacking git-review
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/git-review
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/git-review: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/git-review when looking for download links for git-review
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links for git-review
  Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  URLs to search for versions for git-review:
  * http://pypi.python.org/simple/git-review/
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/git-review/
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/git-review/: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/git-review/ when looking for download links for git-review
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement git-review
No distributions at all found for git-review
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 126, in main
    self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 223, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 948, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 152, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for git-review
```

I've tried using the --proxy option (`--proxy=http://<my_proxy>:<my_port>` with/without the = sign, with/without quotes), but even that shows the same error.

I've also tried setting .pip/pip.conf as follows:

```
[global]
timeout = 60
proxy = http://<my_proxy>:<my_port>
```

As another data point, in case it helps, `nslookup` from the command line fails for domains outside the corporate intranet, but works for domains inside it.  As mentioned, however, Firefox and apt-get seem to have no issues resolving domain names using the proxy.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using a different DNS server on `/etc/resolv.conf`, such as `8.8.8.8`?

Comment: All that's in resolv.conf is `nameserver 127.0.0.1` and `search <corporate_domain>.com`, presumably being set when the box does DHCP with the corporate network.  Adding 8.8.8.8 and/or 8.8.4.4 has no effect, and if I take out the 127.0.0.1 line, nothing works.

Comment: Is a firewall blocking DNS requests? What about `dig google.com @8.8.8.8`? Have you tried putting `185.31.17.175    pypi.python.org` on `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: Tried that. After I add pypi.python.org to `hosts` manually, I get "timed out" errors instead of "Name or service not known".

Comment: are you getting that while setting `--proxy` on the pip command? You need to both be able to resolve the address *and* connect to the http server

Comment: Got the same problem here with the same symptoms.

Comment: Any luck with this one?  I have the same issue - using ubuntu 14.0 as host with precise guest on virtualbox (vagrant).  I can even wget https://pypi.python.org/simple/ no problem from the vm, just pip that fails.

Comment: I had the same problem using a precise guest, I've tried everything around, and at the end I just finished to run the vagrant box on v14 (trusty64) and it started to works without problem

Comment: had same problem. ended up manually copying/pasting the libraries. worked well

Comment: Had a similar issue, `easy_install` worked for me, though.  So I usually just use that.

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by a bug in pip that was solved back in June 2014

https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1104